# Angular dynamic links throughout application

Tags: angular

I am trying to figure out what is the proper way of implementing dynamic links in angular application. It could be that I'm reinventing the wheel.

Lets say that in some component view I want to add link to my application page.

Static way to do it would be:

```
<a routerLink="/target-page/">Target Page</a>
```

Problem: if in my routes I change the name 'target-page' to 'target-page-2' I have to edit this link in every page I use it.

I was thinking of creating a new js file to collect links and then always generate links from that file.

File: 'links.ts' (which I would include everywhere)

```
links: Array<{ name: string; path: string }> = [
   { name: 'home', path: '/homepage/' },
   { name: 'register', path: '/registration-page/' }
];

function getLink(name: string){
   return links.filter(e=>e.name===name).pop().path;
}
```

File: 'someview.html'

```
<a routerLink="{{ getLink('register') }}">Register</a>
```

However,the problem is that a view does not have access to function "getLink()", I have to re-create it in every component.ts. Is there a way to include this function automatically in every component.ts or access it globally in a view?

Comment: NOTE: NOT put "function" to define a function. BAD: function myfunction(){..}, GOOD, myfunction(){...}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create service `ng g service common`.

Then set function in service file.

```
getlink(name: string){
    return links.filter(e=>e.name===name).pop().path;
}
```

Add service in **providers**.      `// Not required, It depends your angular version.

then , import service in component.

add service in constructor

```
constructor(private commonService:CommonService){
}

//Now call function where you want 
let link = this.commonService.getLink('login');
console.log("Link",link);
```